# Embedded Segger embOS: getaddrinfo translation in gethostbyname

Tags: embedded, getaddrinfo, gethostbyname, embos

I am working on a project with an embedded TCP/IP-socket implementation.

My problem is my overlaying SDK needs needs the function:

> getaddrinfo(
> PCSTR           pNodeName,
> PCSTR           pServiceName,
> const ADDRINFOA *pHints,
> PADDRINFOA      *ppResult
> );

but my underlying embedded "OS" is just providing the function:

> struct* hostent gethostbyname(const char * sName);

Has someone an easy solution how to fake getaddrinfo() for the SDK, without the necessary to write it my self?

https://www.segger.com/downloads/emnet/UM07001 (page 273)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ws2tcpip/nf-ws2tcpip-getaddrinfo

[image]

Comment: emNet != embOS  It is an emNet question, not an embOS question - that is it is not specific you tour RTOS

Comment: `getaddrinfo()` is not a trivial function (https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c.html) you are asking a lot.